# How to execute javascript code after an element is created without jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension which would modify an element in a website. That website sends a lot of ajax call after loading the main document to get page contents (GWT framework architecture). I need to modify the content of that webpage and the element that I want to modify will be created only after all the ajax calls.

let's assume that the id of element that i want to modify is `#idContainer > div > div.container.container\--wider.\\30`, which will be available only after the completion of the ajax call.

so how to execute a js code (via chrome extension -> content script) after this element is available.

Note:
I have seen many similar questions in stackOverflow but none of them have answers without using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). Here is an example of some of my projects where I had to solve the exact same problem.

```
// observer callback
const callback = (mutations) => {
  const matching = [];
  for (const {addedNodes} of mutations) { // for each mutation
    for (const node of addedNodes) { // iterate through all added nodes
      if (node.nodeType !== Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        continue; // only react to real element nodes
      }
      if (node.children[0]) { // Here you can check for what you want
        matching.push(...node.getElementsByTagName('pre'));
      }
    }
  }
  if (matching.length === 2) { // I needed the second pre tag
    ipcRenderer.send('note-result', matching[1].innerText);
  }
};

// intialize the observer with the callback
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
// pass a targetNode and an options object in the observe method
observer.observe(document.body, {attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true});
```

*In this example I was interested in the textContent of the second "pre" tag that appeared in the DOM.*

You can also stop observing with the disconnect method:

```
observer.disconnect();
```

You have to adjust the code somewhat to your particular use case but this is the gist of using a mutation observer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing a Chrome extension, you should probably use the [`chrome.webRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) API and [`onCompleted`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onCompleted) event

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(function callback)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think mutation observer will be better option here than chrome.webRequest API because on doing this i want to keep track of all ajax call happening on that page and trigger the script on completion of all the ajax calls which would be complex